# fetching data using retrofit into the Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, onclicklistener

```
*holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // transaction to the targeted fragment from current fragment
            AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();
            Fragment myFragment = new open_order();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_order_frag, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();         
        }
    });*
```

This is code from my adapter class and i want to open a fragment whenever an item is clicked, the data in fragment must be fetched according to what item is clicked.

I have a Recycler View and it contains a list of orders and suppose there are 3 orders with invoice no. 1,2,3 respectively i want open an order by an item click and fetch data in fragment for that clicked item an it must be fetched according to that invoice no or that item as i am using only one fragment for feched data.

Any Suggestions ?

Thank you !

Comment: use bundle for fragments

Comment: can u add piece of code what u had tried ?

Comment: @Prashant singh please post your code

Comment: @Prashantsingh Brother, check my answer as mentioned below,.... set this bundle on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all you will need broadcast so you can send your clicked 
>   info from adapter to your fragment

**1- CREATE BroadcastHelper CLASS :**

```
 public class BroadcastHelper {
     public static final String BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME = "INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED";
    public static final String ACTION_NAME = "hassan.hossam";
    private static final String UPDATE_LOCATION_METHOD = "updateLocation";


    public static void sendInform(Context context, String method) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(ACTION_NAME);
        intent.putExtra(BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME, method);
        try {
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void sendInform(Context context, String method, Intent intent) {
        intent.setAction(ACTION_NAME);
        intent.putExtra(BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME, method);
        try {
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**2- Send intent from your adapter**

```
   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent url = new Intent("url");
            url ("url_adapter",item.get(position).getURL());
            BroadcastHelper.sendInform(context,"url",url);
        }
    });
```

**3- in your fragment this use :**

```
 Receiver receiver;
boolean isReciverRegistered = false;


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (receiver == null) {
        receiver = new Receiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BroadcastHelper.ACTION_NAME);
        getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        isReciverRegistered = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (isReciverRegistered) {
        if (receiver != null)
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}


private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.v("r", "receive " + arg1.getStringExtra(BroadcastHelper.BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME));
        String methodName = arg1.getStringExtra(BroadcastHelper.BROADCAST_EXTRA_METHOD_NAME);
        if (methodName != null && methodName.length() > 0) {
            Log.v("receive", methodName);
            switch (methodName) {

                case "url":

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), url_adapter , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> note you can use This broadcast for anything not just adapter for example you can use it to notify your main activty with new updates from anywhere in your app.

Comment: what this url should be in step 2 and also url adapter

Comment: and also can you tell me if i am using retrofit for data fetching then also i have to follow the same procedure

Comment: its just name of the intent you can set it to anything you want for exp : you can call it ("username",item.get(position).getName());
and item.get(postion).getname is the value you need to send.
about 2nd question yes you can simple : put your fetch method inside 
case "url":

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), url_adapter , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

Comment: Alright thanks a lot ....... also i am curious to know that in my interface What @GET annotation i should use for fetching the data

Comment: that will depends if you have your retrofit already set and ready also depends on your back-end code but most likely it will look like this 
    @GET("taxons/category")
    Call<Category_Model> Category_Model(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization);

Comment: and that Authorization is the field that i want to match ? like my invoice_no.

Comment: Authorization is the token you need to send to the server (if its required, you will need to check with your back-end person about that)

Comment: thanks a lot brother this discussion with you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending data **activity** to **fragment** :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("KEY", "VALUE");
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);    // set Fragmentclass Arguments
```

while you are getting data into **fragment** :

```
String str = getArguments().getString("KEY");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but i have edited my question with the real problem i'm facing take a look and tell me if u can help

Comment: @Prashantsingh don't use setOnClick use onItemClick Listener

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article

        ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // in case your list is of custom objects
        //args.putParcelableArrayList("prgmUri", prgmUri);
        //in case of string arraylist
        //args.putStringArrayList("prgmName", prgmName);
        args.putInt("selected", position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
```

Your can use the `setArguments()`  to pass the bundle to the fragment .

Either u can send the list in the bundle.

Or

Inside the bundle you can change the value of position to be different for fruits(0) and veletable(1) case. 
On retrieving it in fragment , you could decide which list to retrieve.
And use the list.

Inside the fragment :-

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("key");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Brother !Thanks for your response but i have edited my question with the real problem i'm facing take a look and tell me if u can help

Comment: just setTag(position) on the itemView, on which the listner is attached , inside the onclick,  u can get the position of the item clicked by  view.getTag(), and then use this item in this postion of your list, and send the item info using the setArguments() to the next fragment.